# Flutter Refreshing Stateful widget

Tags: flutter, listview, setstate, stateful

I have a Stateful class with displays List as follows:

```
            Container(
                margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(50.0, 10.0, 15.0, 10.0),
                height: 190,
                width: 100,
                child: ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: gameManager.yourScoresList.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return ListTile(
                        visualDensity: VisualDensity(
                            vertical: VisualDensity.minimumDensity),
                        title: gameManager.yourScoresList[index],
                      );
                    }))
```

However, when I clear yourScoresList.clear() from another class (GameManager) ListView is not cleared (ie continues to display existing) until I select another widget in the Stateful class, which implements setState().
I have tried to wrap ListView in ValueListenableBuilder but I cannot get this to work. Any suggestions gratefully received.

Comment: You have to call `setState` from that other class.

Answer (score 0):

As Christopher Moore said, you have to setState in that class, like,

```
void clearbox(){

setState((){

yourScoresList.clear();

});
```

If you don't have StateFulWidget in your another class, then do this,

In your StateFulWidget,(the current class, in which you have the listView)

add this function,

```
void clear(){
setState((){
gameManager.yourScoresList.clear();
});

}
```

call this function, whenever you wish to clear the list, you can even call this from that another class in which you have the list.

Comment: But setState() is not defined in my calling class?

Comment: It is, actually, you are using a class which extends StateFulW, thus it does have. Just copy and paste the code, it'll work.

Comment: i have updated my answer, you can now clear the list, even from your other class, just call this function from that class. Please upvote and accept this as the answer, if it helped :)

Comment: If I include the clear() method in my StatefulWidget it says setState() is undefined for this type:

Comment: class ComputerPlay extends StatefulWidget {

void clear(){
  setState((){
  gameManager.yourScoresList.clear();
  });
}
  @override
  _ComputerPlayState createState() => _ComputerPlayState();
}